# Formatting Decimals in MySQL without the leading 0

Tags: mysql, floating-point, format, decimal

Is there any way to store the float value .999 instead of 0.999 in MySQL(ie.  is there a way to get rid of the zero in front of the decimal)

Comment: That's a presentation layer issue, not something to fix in the database.

Comment: If you're storing it in a float/double column, then no. That's a display issue and you shouldn't be trying to force MySQL to work differently. If it's a char/varchar field,then store it without the 0 in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you store it as a string, no. If you want to display it like that, then use your language of choice to format it.

Comment: that's too bad.. would make life a lot simpler.  Thanks for the clarification.